# django template slice css behaviour

Tags: css, django, templates, slice

I was working on a small blogging engine for fun which allows for html contents. Also on the home page every blog post is sliced to 500 and displayed.

While I was coding this element it struck me that such a slice could be very dangerous. Assuming there is a `<b></b>` tag in the blog post which is sliced after the tag is opened, this would make every other content of the home page become bold.

I was wondering if Django itself has any mechanism to slice only after an html element has been completely closed or if there is any other way in which such a problem can be solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `truncatewords_html` template filter takes into account tags that might have been opened but not closed given the slice.

Take a look in the docs at: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/builtins/#truncatewords-html for the filter's use and have a look at line 140 in django/utils/text.py at the `_html_words()` function which is leveraged by `truncatewords_html`

Comment: this is brilliant. I knew django had to have some sort of implementation for this, like for almost everything else.

Comment: Yeah, Django is simply the most badass web framework I've ever used :)